# Error "Failed to get driver instance for jdbcUrl" while starting up external Tom Cat with Spring Boot war

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, gradle

I have a spring boot gradle project where the DB credentials are defined in application.properties. While starting the application from STS, it is running fine . But when I am building the war and deploying into external apache Tom cat , it is throwing the below error :

> "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in
> com.bt.cyclone.config.JpaConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory
> method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]:
> Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
> Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in
> com.xxx.xclone.config.JpaConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory
> method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw
> exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to
> get driver instance for
> jdbcUrl=jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.com)(PORT=xxxx))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xxx)))"

Please help to solve the problem as it has to be deployed into Production.

Comment: I suggest to you to check if driver is available in server and the server can establish connection to the database

Comment: Yes ... available ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.0.jar into apache-tomcat-8.5.57\lib

Comment: are you not packing the ojdbc jar in your war ?

Comment: Since, this is a spring boot project, everything is bundles into war. Also , the application is running fine with embedded tomcat in STS. But after building into war and deploying into the external tomcat, this error is showing , and the server is failed to start.

Comment: @IB1990 you got any solution on this? I am also facing similar issue.